# pillow conversion increases image size

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-conversion

I am using the python Pillow library to do a simple image format conversion.

Here is some simple code demonstrating what I'm doing

```
im = Image.open("images/filename.tiff", mode="r")
im.save("images/filename.png", optimize=True)
```

This results in on average, a size increase of 98%. Here is the data on the input tiffs I'm trying to create:

```
<image mode=1 size=2544x2230>
```

When I explicitly convert it (by calling .convert(), the size only increases on average by 87%, but still terrible. Why is the size ballooning so much?

Here is what I have tried?

- using the "quality" parameter on .save() seems to have little effect
- explicitly passing the "mode" parameter to the save command has little effect
- using the .convert("L") has little effect on overall size after conversion

**EDIT**

Here is a sample image that ran through what I described above and resulted in an 87% bigger png file, 907% bigger jpeg, and 907% bigger jpg.

https://share.getcloudapp.com/YEuR9LqP

Version of Pillow is latest: 8.2

Python version: 3.8

Running on MacOS: 10.15.7

Am I missing something obvious or this just my lack of knowledge of how the Image library works?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious, so suggest that you report a bug to the maintainers of `pillow`.

Comment: Kindly share a link to your input and output image.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Unfortunately I can't not as they are confidential images. Most of the images we get are just scanned black and white documents. Any obvious things I can try?

Comment: It's quite hard to guess what the problem is when someone says *"an image you can't see got bigger when I changed it into another image you also can't see, on a platform I didn't mention using an unspecified version of PIL"*

Comment: fair enough, you're right. I edited the question and included one of the images along with its size after conversions. Maybe you could run it through pillow on your end and see what results you get? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that your image is [CCITT Group4 Compressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_4_compression), which is particularly well suited to your image content and has no equivalent in PNG format.

```
exiftool image-1.tiff
```

**Output**

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.00
File Name                       : image-1.tiff
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 95 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2021:05:17 11:46:57+01:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2021:05:17 11:57:15+01:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2021:05:17 11:46:58+01:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : TIFF
File Type Extension             : tif
MIME Type                       : image/tiff
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Image Width                     : 2544
Image Height                    : 2230
Bits Per Sample                 : 1
Compression                     : T6/Group 4 Fax       <--- HERE IT IS
Photometric Interpretation      : WhiteIsZero
Strip Offsets                   : 180
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
Rows Per Strip                  : 2230
Strip Byte Counts               : 96954
X Resolution                    : 300
Y Resolution                    : 300
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Image Size                      : 2544x2230
Megapixels                      : 5.7
```

On my Mac, I got an output PNG from PIL of size 138,200 bytes, even using `pngcrush` I could only get down to 124,810 bytes:

```
pngcrush -bruteforce result-opt.png crushed.png
  Recompressing IDAT chunks in result-opt.png to crushed.png
  Total length of data found in critical chunks            =    138200
  Best pngcrush method        =   4 (ws 15 fm 0 zl 9 zs 1) =    124816
```

Comment: ok thanks. so I'm out of luck for converting it without increasing size? I appreciate it, my knowledge of image types/compression is only skin deep

Comment: AFAIK, yes, you are out of luck with PNG. Or you could choose to be positive and optimistic and say that you are already fully optimised with TIFF ;-)

Comment: Just to follow up the whole reason I was going down this path is because these images are going into a PDF generated by Reportlab. Unfortunately whenever I feed in the tiff images, the size of the PDF blows up.